# Adding files to gulpfile.js with ASP.NET 5

Tags: gulp, asp.net-core

ASP.NET Core (i.e. ASP.NET 5) in Visual Studio 2015 creates two (2) different folders that it places Javascript files in:

- **js**, and
- **lib**

The **path** variable as defined in the gulpfile.js file created by Visual Studio is:

```
var paths = {
    js: webroot + "js/*.js",
    minJs: webroot + "js/*.min.js",
    css: webroot + "css/*.css",
    minCss: webroot + "css/*.min.css",
    concatJsDest: webroot + "js/site.min.js",
    concatCssDest: webroot + "css/site.min.css"
};
```

From what I understand, everything in the folder **js** that follows the `*.js` naming convention is added to the path's `js` variable.

Visual Studio was also kind enough to create me that **lib** folder, too, with jQuery included. That folder, however, does not appear to be included in the `js` variable.

[image: screenshot]

- How would I append the jQuery files?
- Are the jQuery files already included somehow?

I can't seem to find much information on ASP.NET 5

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I can write the **path** variable like this:

```
var paths = {
    js: [
        webroot + "js/*.js",
        webroot + "lib/bootstrap/dist/js/*.js",
        webroot + "lib/jquery/dist/*.js",
        webroot + "lib/jquery.validation/dist/*.js",
        webroot + "lib/jquery.validate.unobtrusive/*.js"
    ],
    minJs: webroot + "js/*.min.js",
    css: [
        webroot + "css/*.css",
        webroot + "lib/bootstrap/dist/css/*.css",
        webroot + "splash/*.css"
    ],
    minCss: webroot + "css/*.min.css",
    concatJsDest: webroot + "js/site.min.js",
    concatCssDest: webroot + "css/site.min.css"
};
```

The **gulpfile.js** file seems to be happy with that.

Now, in my **_Layout.cshtml** file, I can reference them like this:

```
<link type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/site.css" />
<link type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/site.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/js/site.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/js/site.min.js")"></script>
```

I don't know how to get the program to tell it when to include the full version verses the minified version, though.